# Can the mean of 2 consecutive prime numbers be prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

This is apparently a "hard" question, and I don't know if I'm missing something, but it seems trivial to me. Aside from 2, all other prime numbers are odd. So the mean of any consecutive prime number is of course even and hence divisible by 2. So the answer is obviously no.

Am I missing something here or is this problem really this simple?

Comment: You're confusing "sum" and "mean" in your reasoning.

Comment: The mean of $7$ and $11$ is $9$.

Comment: $7+11$ is indeed even, but the mean of $7$ and $11$ is $9$.

Comment: Hint:  That "consecutive" bit is the point.  The mean is between the two numbers.

Comment: Without the "consecutive" requirement, there are plenty of examples of the mean of two primes being prime. For examples, $\frac{3+7}{2}=5$ and $\frac{5+17}{2}=11$.

Comment: It would be good if you clarified what you mean by mean.

Comment: @halrankard I think I brain farted.

Comment: If the mean is prime as well, the primes cannot be consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

No, the mean of two numbers is necessarily between them. If there were a prime between your two primes, they would no longer be consecutive.

Comment: looks like I botched this problem with my first thought, but nonetheless, it seems this problem is simple based on your approach.